# ¿Cómo transformar un csv en un geojson?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, geojson

Intento transformar una dataframe en geojson gracias a las coordinadas:

```
>>> df2_province
    Unique_Code Aspirational Youth  Average Empty Nest Mothers  Forgotten   IST OTH PAM PJD RNI Snowflakes  Urban Professional  longitude   latitude    Province
0   01.051. 11  17  28  13  2   13  24  3   0   30  0   -3.931747   35.24456    Al Hoceima
1   01.151. 15  40  20  40  4   8   21  2   2   12  0   -5.268364   35.16880    Chefchaouen

df2_province.to_json("donnees_agregees_province.json")
```

Hice la siguiente función:

```
#! usr/bin/env python

from sys import argv
from os.path import exists
import simplejson as json 

def to_geojson(in_file,out_file):
    data = json.load(open(in_file, encoding="utf8"))

    geojson = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [d["longitude"], d["latitude"]],
                },
            "properties" : d,
         } for d in data]
    }


    output = open(out_file, 'w')
    json.dump(geojson, output)
```

Sin embargo me devuelve:

to_geojson("donnees_agregees_province.json","donnees_agregees_province.geojson")
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
     in 
    ----> 1 to_geojson("donnees_agregees_province.json","donnees_agregees_province.geojson")

```
<ipython-input-190-34a21856ab8a> in to_geojson(in_file, out_file)
     18                 },
     19             "properties" : d,
---> 20          } for d in data]
     21     }
     22 

<ipython-input-190-34a21856ab8a> in <listcomp>(.0)
     18                 },
     19             "properties" : d,
---> 20          } for d in data]
     21     }
     22 

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Desconozco la estructura del CSV que estás utilizando, pero ¿tal vez estás leyendo encabezados sin filtrarlos de tus datos?

Comment: Puedes subir un estracto de la estructura del archivo json que estas cargando? Pareciera que data es un iterable que contiene no solo diccionarios, si no que un string en algun lugar que provoca el error. Esto dado que estas indexando con el string d['longitude'], probablemente d toma el valor de un string en alguna iteracion que provoca la caida.